# Access CMutableVoidPointer value on Swift Language

Tags: xcode, swift

I have the following source code on Swift Language. I didn't find and method to read the array values on takesAMutableVoidPointer function. May I have the advice to read the array values?

```
func takesAMutableVoidPointer (x: CMutableVoidPointer) {
    // TODO: How to read the array values
}

var a: Float[] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
takesAMutableVoidPointer (&a)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? You wouldn't really use that pointer from swift, you would use this to bridge swift code to C and interact with the array using a C implementation of this function.

Comment: I am trying migrate objective-c code to Swift. That's my reason to read the array value.

Comment: I still don't understand. If you have a swift method, just pass the array and access as a swift array. If you have an objc method, just pass the array and access it as an `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0):

When working with Swift types you will more than likely *never* need to use the pointer types or any other C-type for that matter. These are used when interfacing with legacy code in Obj-C or C, like with GCD and other frameworks.

If you are passing objects around in Swift code, you can just access them normally:

```
func takesSomeFloats(array: Float[])
{
    for float in array { println(float) }
}

var a : Float[] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
takesSomeFloats(a)
```

Now, let's say you are wanting to use `dispatch_once` from Grand Central Dispatch (GCD). It has a signature of:

```
func dispatch_once(_ predicate: CMutablePointer<dispatch_once_t>, _ block: dispatch_block_t!)
```

It needs a `CMutablePointer<dispatch_once_t>`, which we can pass like so:

```
var dispatchToken : dispatch_once_t = 0
dispatch_once(&dispatchToken) { /* do something here */ }
```

We do not need to actually worry about creating or casting a pointer type, Swift handles that for us.

Comment: My intention is manipulate the CMutableVoidPointer object. May I know how to print the array with CMutableVoidPointer?